# rgbdslam runs without issues, but octomap does not connect/receive pointcloud (transforms?)

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, rgbdslam-freiburg, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed rgbdslam and octomap. Have been trying to run rgbdslam with octomap. Eventual goal is to get the MarkerArray /occupied_cells_vis_array as it should. Some things I've done:

> METHOD 1

1. Tried to run kinect+rgbdslam.launch and octomap_server.launch.
2. Open rviz and nothing is received on the `/octomap_point_cloud_array`,  `/occupied_cells_vis_array`, `/rgbdslam/aggregate_clouds` OR `/rgbdslam/batch_clouds`. The only PointCloud2 topics that displays an output are `/camera/depth_registered/points`.

> METHOD 2

1. Tried to run rgbdslam_octomap.launch. Worked as well, but due to the color_octomap_server_node not found under octomap_server package (I believe there are some posts saying that you need the experimental version of octomap and some posts saying that the octomap_server is by default colored) I edited it so that it reads octomap_server_node.
2. Runs as well, also gives the same problem as above.

> METHOD 3

While invoking the above scenario, I ran the following commands:

Running`roswtf`
gives that node subscription is unconnected:
*/rgbdslam:
*/cloud_in

Running `rosrun tf view_frames`
gives `camera_link > /camera_rgb_frame > /camera_rgb_optical_frame` and `camera_link > /camera_depth_frame > /camera_depth_optical_frame`. Two branches only.

Running`rostopic_list`
The expect topics are listed:
`/cloud_in`
`/octomap_point_cloud_array`
`/occupied_cells_vis_array`
`/rgbdslam/batch_clouds`
`/rgbdslam/aggregate_clouds`
`/tf`

Running `rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui send_all` did not change the above results.

**I think it is a mapping issue and that the point clouds are not transformed to the correct topics. I am not sure which point cloud problem it is. Please give some pointers as how I can solve this problem.**

**EDIT 05/28/14 +1h: The issue lies in the transform. /map is not present in my frames.pdf view. Not sure how to solve this problem either.**

**EDIT 06/04/14: Solved building octomap using rgbdslam data by recording a .bag file, launching octomap_server, and viewing it in RViz. No fix for continuous rgbdslam mapping and trajectory output found yet.**

> rgbdslam_octomap.launch

```
<launch>
  <env name="ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE" value="$(find rgbdslam)/log.conf"/>
  
  <!--might only work with the experimental octomap (as of May 11)-->
    <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>
    <node pkg="rgbdslam" type="rgbdslam" name="rgbdslam" cwd="node" required="false" output="log" > 
      <param name="config/topic_image_mono"              value="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
      <param name="config/topic_points"                  value="/camera/rgb/points"/> <!--if empty, poincloud will be reconstructed from image and depth -->
      <param name="config/wide_topic"                    value=""/>;
      <param name="config/wide_cloud_topic"              value=""/>;
      <param name="config/drop_async_frames"             value="true"/> <!-- Check association of depth and visual image, reject if not in sync -->
      <param name="config/feature_detector_type"         value="SIFTGPU"/><!-- If SIFTGPU is enabled in CMakeLists.txt, use SURF here -->
      <param name="config/feature_extractor_type"        value="SIFTGPU"/><!-- If SIFTGPU is enabled in CMakeLists.txt, use SURF here -->
      <param name="config/matcher_type"                  value="FLANN"/> <!-- FLANN (not avail for ORB features), SIFTGPU (only for SIFTGPU detector)  or BRUTEFORCE-->
      <param name="config/max_keypoints"                 value="700"/><!-- Extract no more than this many keypoints (not honored by SIFTGPU)-->
      <param name="config/min_keypoints"                 value="300"/><!-- Extract no less than this many ... -->
      <param name="config/nn_distance_ratio"             value="0.6"/> <!-- Feature correspondence is valid if distance to nearest neighbour is smaller than this parameter times the distance to the 2nd neighbour -->
      <param name="config/optimizer_skip_step"           value="1"/><!-- optimize every n-th frame -->
      <param name="config/optimizer_iterations"          value="4"/><!-- optimize every n-th frame -->
      <param name="config/store_pointclouds"             value="true"/> <!-- if, e.g., only trajectory is required, setting this to false saves lots of memory -->
      <param name="config/backend_solver"                value="pcg"/>
      <param name="config/individual_cloud_out_topic"    value="/rgbdslam/batch_clouds"/>;
      <param name="config/visualization_skip_step"       value="1"/> <!-- draw only every nth pointcloud row and line, high values require higher squared_meshing_threshold -->
      <param name="config/send_clouds_rate"              value="2"/> <!-- When sending the point clouds (e.g. to RVIZ or Octomap Server) limit sending to this many clouds per second -->
      <param name="config/min_time_reported"             value="0.01"/><!-- for easy runtime analysis -->
      <param name="config/min_translation_meter"         value="0.05"/><!-- frames with motion less than this, will be omitted -->
      <param name="config/min_rotation_degree"           value="1"/><!-- frames with motion less than this, will be omitted -->
      <param name="config/predecessor_candidates"        value="5"/><!-- search through this many immediate predecessor nodes for corrspondences -->
      <param name="config/neighbor_candidates"           value="5"/><!-- search through this many graph neighbour nodes for corrspondences -->
      <param name="config/min_sampled_candidates"        value="5"/><!-- search through this many uniformly sampled nodes for corrspondences -->
    </node>

    <!-- Launch octomap_server for mappingL: Listens to incoming PointCloud2 data 
    and incrementally build an octomap. The data is sent out in different representations. -->
    <node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server" output="screen">
      <param name="resolution" value="0.005" />
      <!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
      <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="map" />
      <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup, accuracy) -->
      <param name="max_sensor_range" value="6.0" />
      <!-- Save octomap here on destruction of the server -->
      <param name="save_directory" value="$(optenv OCTOMAP_SAVE_DIR ./)" />
      <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
      <remap from="cloud_in" to="/rgbdslam/batch_clouds" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170996/rgbdslam-runs-without-issues,-but-octomap-does-not-connect/receive-pointcloud-(transforms?)/) by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved. The problem of not seeing /rgbdslam/batch_clouds or /occupied_cells_vis_array was solved by this thread:
http:// answers.ros.org/question/53228/rgbdslam-cannot-produce-octomap/#53511

The problem is solved by having to "send_file" or ctrl+M in RGBDSLAM view at each frame. Then toggle the topics in RVIZ to show your desired topic.

No solution was given to *continuous map building by RGBDSLAM* yet. Will be posting questions on this later.

---

Originally posted by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) with karma: 101 on 2014-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on 2014-05-28**:
25 pts required to accept your own answer. Anyone that would like to close this for me is appreciated.

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-06-09**:
Hi @loutifner ! Are you trying to do something like online SLAM and map creation for path planning and navigation? I also need what you have achieved so to obtain coordinates of a possible path a exploring UAV can follow. I'll be using rgbdslam+path planing pkg to do it so. Tips needed! Thanks